# How do I export data that contains tabs and other arbitrary characters from Hive to disk?

Tags: hive, csv

For example:

```
hive -e "select '\t' as a, ',' as b, 1 as c" > output.txt
```

The tabs are not escaped in the output file, even though they are used as a delimiter.

How can I ensure I can use a full ASCII map of characters when outputting data from Hive?

Comment: Does that mean, you need "\t" as string in your data instead of actual tab?

Answer (score -1):

Try this answer if that helps:

```
select "\\t" as a, "\," as b
```